# Uploading file to S3 using Alamofire returns error

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, alamofire

I'm trying to upload a file to S3 using a pre-signed request.

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

    //Attempt 1
    multipartFormData.append(InputStream(data: data), withLength: UInt64(data.count), headers: [
            "Content-Type": " "
            ])

    //Attempt 2
    //multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "file", fileName: fileName, mimeType: "application/json")

}, with: router) { encodingResult in

        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload,_,_):
            upload.validate()
            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { progress in

                guard let progressCallback = progressCallback else { return }
                progressCallback(progress.fractionCompleted)
            })

            upload.responseString(completionHandler: { response in

                switch response.result {
                case .success(let json):
                    self.handleSuccessResponse(withJson: json, toCallback: callback)
                case .failure(let error):
                    self.handleFailResponse(withData: response.data, toCallback: callback)
                }
            })

        case .failure:
            break
        }
    }
```

I'm getting Status code `403`

and response:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error>

<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>************</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>POST\n\nmultipart/form-data; 
boundary=alamofire.boundary.e001fb3981bbd6fc\n1522072451\nx-amz- 
server-side-encryption:AES256\n/api/****/test.json</StringToSign>
```

If i understand correctly the problen is the  `boundary=alamofire.boundary.e001fb3981bbd6fc`

How do i remove this?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the AWS iOS sdk ?https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3CreateMultipartUploadRequest.html

Comment: @strongjz I rather not add another SDK only for uploading a file. This should be a simple task using Alamofire

Comment: @strongjz any other suggestions? if i cant find an answer i will use the SDK

Comment: Who is generating the presigned url for you? Also yes, i think that header is causing you issues.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html

Comment: Are server is generating the presigned url